# How to back up a MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server, backup, database

I have a MSSQL databse hosted on a windows server, What do I need to download a back up to my pc?
I am familiar with backing up MSSQL databases, I believe I need to download a Microsoft database management program is this correct?

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question. Your question is broad and tells us nothing about which specific problems you are facing.

Comment: Hi, user40709, I voted you up. Do not discourage yourself just because half a dozen guys here earned here big scores to pass time downvoting people who have doubts and questions. If to ultimately to formulate correctly the question then it would not contain even anything to ask.

Comment: downvote here, too. Same argument as Mitch Wheat.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to restore the backup to your PC you will need a copy of the SQL database endine running and a copy of SQL management studio installed.  Check out [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/)

Answer (score 0):

One can restore (added later - or backup) database from command line. The advantage of this is that it does not require SSMS (MS SQL Server Management Studio) setup. I sure you find a plethora of articles to choose from according to your taste through "googling" (searching on internet)

Look for SqlCmd in BOL or internet to backup/restore from command line

Comment: He's looking to backup, not restore...

Comment: He is looking "download a back up to my pc?' obviously to restore then. Though what is the difference? backup/restore are symmetrical paired activities done by the same tools or approaches approaches (there is no backup without restore and no restore without backup)

Comment: Backup and restore are two distinctly different tasks.  Both have very different sets of steps.  Backups can exist without restores but restores cannot exist without a backup.  They are also not necessarily done with the same set of tools.

Comment: Instead of telling someone to google it, you could instead provide links to some of the information you're telling them to google for.

Comment: your answers, and subsequent comments to others are becoming increasingly irritating. We don't know that he is "obviously trying to restore", because it wasn't stated.